# Jquery conflict between fancydropdown menu and fancybox gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, conflict

I'm using fancydropdownmenu and fancybox image gallery on a site and there appears to be a conflict between the jquery referencing. Whichever JS file is referenced last in 
the HTML head overrides the other. 'fancydropdown.js' has a copy JQuery 1.3 in the top of the file which I think is conflicting with the JQuery link in the head of the HTML document. I've tried deleting what I think is the JQuery content out of the .js file with no success. I've also tried .noconflict and replacing '$' with 'jquery'. I may be doing it all wrong as I'm a total noobie. Any help would be really apreciated... going nuts! The URL is [www.amuletbhutan.com](http://www.amuletbhutan.com)
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is not working ? your menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *fancybox* requires jQuery v1.3+ and *fancydropdown* menu already includes *jQuery* v1.3.2, you could delete the following line from your `<head>` section to avoid further conflicts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You only need a single instance of jQuery (ideally the latest version) to avoid such conflicts.

You may try to deleted the jQuery part from the `fancydropdown.js` (everything before `/* Sizzle CSS Selector Engine - v0.9.3`) otherwise.

`.noconflict` is used when you have other javascript libraries in the same document like prototype or mootools but it's not your case.

Comment: Yes! Your first solution worked perfectly. As usual, I think I pretty much did everything except that one option! Thank you much. Lifesaver!